# Xpages: Dynamic View Panel and DominoViewCustomizer bean

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have dynamic view panel and I am using a customizer bean to hide columns based on column names. However, I need to:

1. Know which view is loaded in the customizer bean
2. get document handle in the bean
3. add additional column in the bean

Why I need this: in my application I am dealing with document mappings. I want to create a column for mapped document details. as there can be different document types mapped, there can be multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work of seeing which view you're working with and generating the column defs (normally the same as the ones in the view, but you could add others) is done via the `ViewFactory` object that is returned by `#getViewFactory` in the customizer bean. You can see an example of overriding the method and returning a customized factory [here](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding/blob/9e4e70e88b1a447524f7edb785c4218fc1209aa6/frostillicus.framework/frostillicus.framework.plugin/src/main/java/frostillicus/xsp/DynamicViewCustomizer.java#L47). You can also find the source of the default one in the ExtLib [here](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/e773f57fa3d0a7dce6ca1edd46bfc9b3646a0d08/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino/src/com/ibm/xsp/extlib/component/dynamicview/ViewDesign.java#L252) for another example. The job of the `ViewFactory` is to emit a `ViewDef` containing a series of `ColumnDef`s - basically, an abstract representation of the view design. That will cover 1 and 3.

Getting a handle on the document in question for number 2 is a bit more indirect. Since the customizer bean executes only during the initialization of the view, it has no direct hook to the process of rendering each row (which is where you can get the document). You can, however, set properties or content to method/value bindings that, themselves, access the document, so that they're executed per row. I do this in order to get color columns working: I [create an SSJS binding](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding/blob/9e4e70e88b1a447524f7edb785c4218fc1209aa6/frostillicus.framework/frostillicus.framework.plugin/src/main/java/frostillicus/xsp/DynamicViewCustomizer.java#L353) for the `style` property that can then see the `viewEntry` object. If you modify that code, you could write some SSJS like `#{javascript:var doc = viewEntry.getDocument(); ...other stuff here...}`. If you do that, you should make sure to either always use "viewEntry" as the var name in the view or [use `panel.getVar()` to find the variable name dynamically](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding/blob/9e4e70e88b1a447524f7edb785c4218fc1209aa6/frostillicus.framework/frostillicus.framework.plugin/src/main/java/frostillicus/xsp/DynamicViewCustomizer.java#L385).

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I got this whole idea based on your view customizer but was hoping if there is shortcut starting point for me but apparently there is none. Right now, I went the JSON way and create my table dynamically (urgent delivery) but **in future I'd like to try to inject a column once the view  is created. Do you think it is plausible?** I definitely need to read about all the classes and intefaces in Xpages and ExtLib. May be then I'll be able to architect a solution instead of taking care of things as they come up.

Comment: You could probably add columns dynamically by accessing the component tree at runtime. If you have an action somewhere that does `getComponent(...)` to get the dynamicViewPanel, you could probably then create new `UIDynamicColumn` (or whatever the class is) objects and does `addChild(...)` with them. The same would work with a standard viewPanel if you wanted to do a sort of ad-hoc dynamic view panel without the ExtLib control.